# How to recognize the Docker command and host command

Tags: docker

I am running this command to check the host process:

```
[root@fat001 ~]# ps aux|grep envelope
root     16744  0.7  3.5 4069908 570560 ?      Sl   Jan19 175:21 /opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -Xmx256M -Xms128M -jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5010 /data/jenkins/ws-red-envelope-service/ws-red-envelope-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
root     17933  9.7  2.3 5779896 382364 ?      Sl   19:09   1:39 java -jar /root/soa-red-envelope-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
root     22526  0.0  0.0 112684  1004 pts/11   S+   19:26   0:00 grep --color=auto envelope
root     32040  2.7  4.3 4310300 702868 ?      Sl   Jan15 796:55 /opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -Xmx256M -Xms128M -jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5007 /data/jenkins/soa-red-envelope-service/soa-red-envelope-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but this command (`java -jar /root/soa-red-envelope-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`) is running in Docker of Kubernetes (v1.15.2), how to diff the Docker's command or the host machine's command? Why the host could found Docker's start app command? This is my docker start.sh (running in Docker container, not in host):

```
nohup java -jar /root/soa-revolver-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see your processes in the `ps` output of the host, I'm assuming you're on Linux, and therefore have recent-enough `ps`.

So you can do that:

```
ps -o user,pid,pidns,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,args ax
```

When you do `ps aux`, the `u` part sets the columns that `ps` would show to the equivalent of `-o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,args`.

But if you pass `-o` explicitly instead, you can specify things like `pidns`, which is the PID namespace, which would be some number related to the container, whereas it would just say `-` for host processes.